# What's wrong with this example with string literal?

Tags: c, string, increment

I'm reading an answer from this site which says the following is undefined

```
char *fubar = "hello world";
*fubar++; // SQUARELY UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR!
```

but isn't that `fubar++` is done first, which means moving the pointer to `e`, and `*()` is then done, which means extract the `e` out. I know this is supposed to be asked on chat (I'm a kind person) but no one is there so I ask here to attract notice.

Comment: Do you want to increment the address or the content, for content:  (*fubar)++;  For the address fubar++;

Comment: @SPlatten: I want neither, I just want to know whether it would lead to undefined behaviour as the answer said...

Comment: You have no assignment so there is no point in the '*'.

Comment: Please, note the comment of usr to this linked answer: _Your "SQUARELY UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR" code is in fact perfectly valid (no undefined behaviour)._ This is exactly what I think about it. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: wow, but the time stamp is slightly after mine my question.

Comment: Oops. I was not aware about this. ;-)

Comment: I guess, your question leaded usr to this fact and he left a node at the original place...

Comment: Lesson learned: adhere to the rule of never mixing ++ with other operators in the same expression. It is a bad thing to do for multiple reasons: readability, maintainability, potentially undefined behavior,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code shown is clearly *not* undefined behaviour, since `*fubar++` is somewhat equal to `char result; (result = *fubar, fubar++, result)`, i.e. it increments the pointer, and not the dereferenced value, and the result of the expression is the (dereferenced) value `*fubar` before the pointer got incremented. `*fubar++` actually gives you the character value to which `fubar` originally points, but you simply make no use of this "result" and ignore it.

Note, however, that the following code *does*  introduce undefined behaviour:

```
char *fubar = "hello world";
(*fubar)++;
```

This is because this increments the value to which `fubar` points and thereby manipulates a string literal -> undefined behaviour.

When replacing the string literal with an character array, then everything is OK again:

```
int main() {

    char test[] = "hello world";
    char* fubar = test;
    (*fubar)++;
    printf("%s\n",fubar);
}
```

Output:

```
iello world
```

Answer (score 6):

The location of the `++` is the key: If it's a suffix (like in this case) then the increment happens *after*.

Also due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) you increment the *pointer*.

So what happens is that the pointer `fubar` is dereference (resulting in `'h'` which is then ignored), and then the pointer variable `fubar` is incremented to point to the `'e'`.

In short: `*fubar++` is fine and valid.

If it was `(*fubar)++` then it would be undefined behavior, since then it would attempt to increase the first characters of the string. And literal strings in C are arrays of *read-only* characters, so attempting to modify a character in a literal string would be *undefined behavior*.

---

The expression `*fubar++` is essentially equal to

```
char *temporary_variable = fubar;
fubar = fubar + 1;
*temporary_variable;  // the result of the whole expression
```

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 `*fubar++` is equal to `*(fubar++)`. That is also explained in the answer. Note that since it is a postfix operator the pointer is dereferenced before the increment and then the pointer is incremented.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604, ++(postfix) is meaningless and means nothing since you have no additional operand in the brackets.

Comment: `*fubar++` is equal to `*(fubar++)` which is (mostly) equal to `*fubar; fubar++;`.

Comment: @Osiris: I remember ++(postfix) returns old value or something, but I'm confused now lol.